# Pandas to_sql using wrong data type, can it be changed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I've loaded some SQL Server data into a Pandas Dataframe. Here some transformations take place. Once completed I am trying to dump the Dataframe back into SQL using the SQLAlchemy to_sql function. The destination table is automatically created by SQLAlchemy.

However, I am getting this error message...

```
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

This is because the Dataframe contains a number of date fields. Some of the data in these date fields are set to '0001-01-01' which obviously won't fit into a DATETIME data type, but would fit into a DATETIME2 data type.

Is there a way to force DATETIME2 to be used instead of DATETIME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [DATETIME2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.DATETIME2) as a dtype, as shown below.

```
df.to_sql(
  'Temp',
  target_engine,
  schema = 'dbo',
  if_exists = 'replace',
  chunksize = 250000,
  index = False,
  dtype={"CreatedDate": DATETIME2}
)
```